# Trying to use a DFRobot IR Camera to find infrared lights

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi 3, python 2.7.16, and a DFRobot Positioning IR Camera. I am trying to read IR positioning lights with the camera and then have it do a continuous print. I keep running into an error that can be seen below. I apologize if something is not correct, as this is my first time posting.

I have been working on this project for about a month. I have tried some libraries such as pigpio, but with no success. Below is me making sure the Pi can read the device.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 58 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Below are the 2 Codes I used

#### SeniorDesign_Test.py

```
from SeniorDesign_IRcam import pyIRcam
from time import sleep,time
from Tkinter import *

update_rate = 20 # 20ms update rate

camera = pyIRcam() # Sensor initialization


master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width = 1024, height =768) #IR Camera Dimensions
w.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

def update_Image():
    camera.getPositions() #Update with new IR objects
    w.delete(ALL)
    if camera.positions['found']:
        camera.findTarget()
    if(camera.targetFound):
        color = "blue"
    else:
        color ="red"
        w.create_rectangle(camera.positions['1'][0], camera.positions['1'][1], camera.positions['1'][0] + 10, camera.positions['1'][1] + 10, fill = color)
        w.create_rectangle(camera.positions['2'][0], camera.positions['2'][1], camera.positions['2'][0] + 10, camera.positions['2'][1] + 10, fill = color)
        w.create_rectangle(camera.positions['3'][0], camera.positions['3'][1], camera.positions['3'][0] + 10, camera.positions['3'][1] + 10, fill = color)
        w.create_rectangle(camera.positions['4'][0], camera.positions['4'][1], camera.positions['4'][0] + 10, camera.positions['4'][1] + 10, fill = color)

master.after(0, update_Image)
master.mainloop()
```

#### SeniorDesign_IRCam.py

```
import smbus
import math
from time import sleep
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
degPerPixel = 0.0299947917
ledDistance = 1.3 #In Inches

class pyIRcam:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sensorAddress = 0x58 # address of camera
        self.device = smbus.SMBus(1)
        self.positions = {'found':False,'1':[0,0],'2':[0,0],'3':[0,0],'4':[0,0]}
        # Initialization of the IR sensor
        self.initCMDs = [0x30, 0x01, 0x30, 0x08, 0x06, 0x90, 0x08, 0xC0, 0x1A, 0x40, 0x33, 0x33]

        for i,j in zip(self.initCMDs[0::2], self.initCMDs[1::2]):
            self.device.write_byte_data(self.sensorAddress, i, j)
            sleep(0.01)

    def getPositions(self):
        self.device.write_byte(self.sensorAddress, 0x36)
        data = self.device.read_i2c_block_data(self.sensorAddress, 0x36, 16) # Read the data from the I2C bus
        x = [0x00]*4
        y = [0x00]*4
        i=0

        for j in xrange(1,11,3): # Decode the data coming from the I2C bus
            x[i]=data[j]+((data[j+2] & 0x30) << 4)
            y[i]=data[j+1]+((data[j+2] & 0xC0) << 2)
            i+=1
            i=0

        for j in ('1','2','3','4'): # Put the x and y positions into the dictionary
            self.positions[j][0]=x[i]
            self.positions[j][1]=y[i]
            i+=1

        if ( all(i == 1023 for i in x) and all(i == 1023 for i in y) ): # If all objects are 1023, then there is no IR object in front of the sensor
            self.positions['found'] = False

        else:
                self.positions['found'] = True

    def getDistance(self):
        #getting minimum distance
        distance12 = math.sqrt((self.positions['1'][0] - self.positions ['2'][0]) ** 2 + (self.positions['1'][1] - self.positions['2'][1]) ** 2)
        distance23 = math.sqrt((self.positions['2'][0] - self.positions ['3'][0]) ** 2 + (self.positions['2'][1] - self.positions['3'][1]) ** 2)
        distance13 = math.sqrt((self.positions['1'][0] - self.positions ['3'][0]) ** 2 + (self.positions['1'][1] - self.positions['3'][1]) ** 2)
        distance = min(distance12, distance23, distance13)
        theta = distance * degPerPixel
        phi = 90 - theta / 2
        d = (ledDistance / 2.0) * math.tan (phi * math.pi / 180.0)
        print d
```

It should continuously print out coordinates of where the IR lights are, along with a simple 3 dot image. Instead I get this.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python SeniorDesign_Test.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 599, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "SeniorDesign_Test.py", line 15, in update_Image
    camera.getPositions() #Update with new IR objects
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SeniorDesign_IRcam.py", line 23, in getPositions
    data = self.device.read_i2c_block_data(self.sensorAddress, 0x36, 16) # Read the data from the I2C bus
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```